# SQL UNION - what are the implicit matching conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

If I perform an SQL UNION on 2 tables, what are the explicit conditions that UNION uses to decide that any 2 rows are the same?

Looking through the Postgres documentation, it just states "A row is in the set union of two result sets if [it] appears in at least one of the result sets".  If [WHAT] appears in the result sets?

Does it match column1, then column2, ...?  How does it decide to stop at columnX?

I'm a little stunned that the actual matching rules aren't spelled out explicitly.  Or, I just couldn't find them with 10 minutes of Google-ing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNION (as compared to UNION ALL) is similar to DISTINCT in that for duplicates to be removed, all columns have to be identical.

Comment: cade, thanks - that makes sense.  I've spent most of the day switching between UNION and FULL OUTER JOIN, so I expected UNION to have an ON clause.  It implicitly creates one 'ON every column matching' I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but perhaps this is it.

When you use `union` (or other set operators) on two tables, the rows are compared by *position*.  All columns must match -- that is, there need to be the same number of columns in both tables.  Postgres will decide on the type of each column in the result set based on type precedence rules.  The columns in either table will be converted to the specified type.

Does that address what you are asking?

Actually, this is pretty much specified in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html):

> SQL UNION constructs must match up possibly dissimilar types to become
>   a single result set. The resolution algorithm is applied separately to
>   each output column of a union query. The INTERSECT and EXCEPT
>   constructs resolve dissimilar types in the same way as UNION. The
>   CASE, ARRAY, VALUES, GREATEST and LEAST constructs use the identical
>   algorithm to match up their component expressions and select a result
>   data type.
>
> Type Resolution for UNION, CASE, and Related Constructs
>
> 1. If all inputs are of the same type, and it is not unknown, resolve as
>      that type.
> 2. If any input is of a domain type, treat it as being of the domain's
>      base type for all subsequent steps. [9]
> 3. If all inputs are of type unknown, resolve as type text (the preferred
>      type of the string category). Otherwise, unknown inputs are ignored
>      for the purposes of the remaining rules.
> 4. If the non-unknown inputs are not all of the same type category, fail.
> 5. Choose the first non-unknown input type which is a preferred type in
>      that category, if there is one.
> 6. Otherwise, choose the last non-unknown input type that allows all the
>      preceding non-unknown inputs to be implicitly converted to it. (There
>      always is such a type, since at least the first type in the list must
>      satisfy this condition.)
> 7. Convert all inputs to the selected type. Fail if there is not a
>      conversion from a given input to the selected type.

Comment: Gordon, the 2 table's Column Types match.  My question was instead how does UNION decide the Rows from each table match?  Cade Roux gave the answer that UNION compares every column value, and only considers the row a duplicate if every column matches.  This wasn't obvious to me on reading the PostGres docs.  Thanks!